# capturing .net webservice out parameter using ksoap2

Tags: java, android, ksoap2, webservices-client

i was trying to call a .net webservice with the **Android SDK**, that was simple using the ksoap2 library, including passing and getting complex types.yet i faced a more complicated problem, the
    *SoapSerializationEnvelope.getResult()*
 or *SoapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse()* only gives the return value of the web method,        but when there is out parameters in the method, how can i get them?

i found a work arround to get them by setting the *AndroidHttpTransport.debug=true* and thus being able to get *AndroidHttpTransport.responseDump* and then parsing this xml string and get the values out of it

the thing is that

### isn't there any simpler way to get these out parameters?

excuse me for the bad formatted question, but this is my first time using it:S..

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to [How to retrieve binary data from Web Service in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383746/how-to-retrieve-binary-data-from-web-service-in-android/6386838#6386838)

It shown how to access the response parameters.