# How to retrieve binary data from Web Service in Android?

Tags: java, android, ksoap2

```
   SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);          
   Log.d("WebService", "2");
   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
          new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
   envelope.dotNet = true;
   envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
   HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
   androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);                    
   SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
```

This is the code where I call a .NET web service which sends a byte[] array. How can I get the byte[] array from the **result variable** or is there another approach to retrieve byte[] array?

Comment: Looks like you are using the KSoap2 library for generating the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the presented code is using kSoap2. If you want to access the retrieved data forget about the response object returned by `envelope.getResponse()`.

The data you are looking for can be retrieved via

```
SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
if (resultsRequestSOAP != null) {
  Object o = resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty("name of the byte-array parameter");
  // ...
}
```

The returned Object o is usually of the type `SoapPrimitive` or may be a `Vector`.

If it's a SoapPrimitive using it's `toString()` method you can get the String representation of the byte array that has to be parsed and converted to a byte array.

If it's a Vector I don't think that you will have problems converting it to a byte array.